# How can I float the table of contents to the right with MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki

According to the [MediaWiki FAQ](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/MediaWiki_FAQ#How_do_I_add_a_table_of_contents.3F)

> A TOC is added automatically as soon as you have more than three headers.

which is fine and all, but I'd like it floated to the right, so that it does not take up a lot of vertical space at the top of the page.

How can I float the table of contents to the right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add

```
#toc { float: right };
```

to your `MediaWiki:Common.css` wiki page.

Comment: For any noobs out there (like me), you can access this special page just like any other, with an URL like this: http://my.domain.com/MediaWiki/index.php?title=MediaWiki:Common.css

Comment: ...or by writing the name to site's search box.

Answer (score 8):

For one page use

```
<div style="float:right;">__TOC__</div>
```

This is what I usually do. Being that I do a lot with styling and so forth, I hate using my user css to modify anything since then I don't see what everyone else sees and therefore don't know what a visitor will see.

Comment: Great. I also suggest adding margin (`style="float:right;margin-left:40px"`) so that there is some distance between TOC frame and actual content (looks better this way)

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to do it for one particular page and not all pages the following WikiMarkup should work ([source](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help%3aSection#Table_of_contents_.28TOC.29)):

```
{| align="right"
| __TOC__
|}
```

Comment: This has no effect on the TOC for me, although Arlen's div solution works.

Comment: This does not work after Mediawiki 1.19, but works before. Use Arlen's solution instead: <div style="float:right;">__TOC__</div>

Answer (score 2):

Try using this in the `Mediawiki:common.css` file

```
#toc {float:right;margin:0 0 1em 1em;position:fixed;top:150px;right:10px;};
```

This not only places the floating TOC to the right, but also keeps it visible all the time while scrolling up and down the page.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly I have done to accomplish this:

1. In the search box, type "MediaWiki:Common.css"
2. You will see the MediaWiki:Common.css page that you can now "Create" if you have never made any modifications to id, or "Edit" if you have already created it.
3. Add the following code: #toc {float:right;margin:0 0 1em 1em;position:fixed;top:150px;right:10px;}; and Save your changes.
4. Make sure to clear your cache.
5. Load a page with a Table of content

Thank you for pencilslate code.