# How can I put the ToC at the top of the page, parallel to the first paragraph?

Tags: mediawiki, css

Similarly to [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3851/how-can-i-float-the-table-of-contents-to-the-right-with-mediawiki), I'd like to tweak where the default ToC appears in my MediaWiki site.  Currently it appears at the first header, but occasionally I have significant content in the first paragraphs, before any headers.

Is there any way to make the ToC top-aligned with the page, rather than with the first header?

Comment: According to [a guideline of the English Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:LEADLENGTH), the lead section should not be more than four paragraphs long. You might consider adopting similar guideline on your wiki.

Comment: Agreed.  But even two short paragraphs, or one paragraph and a small table or other special content, can bury the ToC further than I'd like.

Answer (score 1):

As written in [one of the answers](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/3896/2455), ToC can be added anywhere to your page by using the following keyword:

```
__TOC__
```

If you want to add TOC to same place on every page, you can do so by styling it in your `MediaWiki:Common.css` wiki page (which gets added to CSS for all skins used, see [an example of such page on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MediaWiki:Common.css)). Something along the lines of this might work:

```
#toc { position: absolute; top: 2em; right: 0.5em; };
```

Comment: That's something, but it requires making an adjustment on each page.  Is there a way to make the ToC appear at the top of the page by default?

Comment: You can set it to static positioning in global CSS.

Comment: Great!  How?  Put it in an answer and I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: Added a rough attempt :-)

Comment: So close!  That does put the ToC in the top-right corner, but now it overlays content instead of flowing as it did when it was `float: right;`.  If I was writing an ordinary web page, floating would be perfect, because I could change the insertion point.